# How to properly query Data Table in PowerShell

Tags: sql, powershell, datatables

I am attempting to leverage an OleDB using Text Driver within PowerShell to more easily manage a large CSV.

Everything is working, and I can query the data. The problem I am running into is when I attempt to query the Data Table multiple times.

Example:

- First Query: I query the table to provide a count on column 1 which produces 100.
- Second Query: I query the table to provide a number on a different column and I get the same 100 from the first query.

Having a hard time understanding how to clear data from the first query so that the new data results are returned.

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbconnection
$conn.ConnectionString = $connstring
$conn.Open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDB.OleDBCommand
$cmd.Connection = $conn

$checkColumns = "Name, Age"

$data_group_check = "SELECT $checkColumns, COUNT(*) as DupeCount FROM [$tablename]  GROUP BY $checkColumns HAVING COUNT(*) > 1"
$data_online_check =  "SELECT $checkColumns, COUNT(*) as DupeCount FROM [$tablename] WHERE Online LIKE 'yes' GROUP BY $checkColumns HAVING COUNT(*) > 1"
$data_offline_check = "SELECT $checkColumns, COUNT(*) as DupeCount FROM [$tablename] WHERE Online LIKE 'no' GROUP BY $checkColumns HAVING COUNT(*) > 1"


$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$cmd.CommandText = $data_group_check
$dt.BeginLoadData()

# First Query
$dt.Load($cmd.ExecuteReader([System.Data.CommandBehavior]::Default))
$dupecount = $dt.Rows.Count

# Start Second Query
$cmd.CommandText = $data_online_check
$dt.Load($cmd.ExecuteReader([System.Data.CommandBehavior]::Default))
$online_dupes = $dt.Rows.Count

# Start Third Query
$cmd.CommandText = $data_offline_check
$dt.Load($cmd.ExecuteReader([System.Data.CommandBehavior]::CloseConnection))
$offline_dupes = $dt.Rows.Count
$dt.EndLoadData()
$totaltime = [math]::Round($elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds,2)

# Get Total Row Count
$conn.Open()
$cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalRows FROM [$tablename]"
$totalrows = $cmd.ExecuteScalar()
$conn.Close()


  $totalrows 
  $dupecount
  $online_dupes
  $offline_dupes
  $totaltime
```

- $totalrows - Produces 1500000
- $dupecount - Produces 15000
- $online_dupes - Produces 15000 (Should be 2002)
- $offline_dupes - Produces 15000 (Should be 3040)

If I run each query separately I get the correct numbers.

Between the first and second/third query is there something I need to clear?

Comment: Have you tried `$dt.Clear()` yet?

Comment: Hello Theo,  Thank you for the response. I have tried $dt.Clear() which then causes the subsequent queries to return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with only one query like this :

```
SELECT $checkColumns, 
sum(case when Online = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) NbYes,
sum(case when Online = 'no' then 1 else 0 end) NbNo,
COUNT(*) as DupeCount 
FROM [$tablename]  
GROUP BY $checkColumns 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
or sum(case when Online = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)>1
or sum(case when Online = 'no' then 1 else 0 end)>1
```

or like this:

```
SELECT 'DUPLICATE 1' TypeDuplicate, $checkColumns, COUNT(*) as DupeCount 
FROM [$tablename]  
GROUP BY $checkColumns 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

UNION ALL
SELECT 'DUPLICATE 2' TypeDuplicate, $checkColumns, COUNT(*) as DupeCount 
FROM [$tablename] 
WHERE Online = 'yes' 
GROUP BY $checkColumns 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

UNION ALL
SELECT 'DUPLICATE 3' TypeDuplicate, $checkColumns, COUNT(*) as DupeCount 
FROM [$tablename] 
WHERE Online = 'no' 
GROUP BY $checkColumns 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```